# Return reference to stl vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, reference

Im building a small C++ program and I'm implementing custom operators in a class. Also I'm working with STL vectors.

However I'm stuck at the beginning. Here's my interface class:

```
class test {

    vector<string> v;
    public:
         vector<string>& operator~();      
};
```

And here's the implementation:

```
vector< string>& test::operator~(){

    return v;
}
```

I want to return a reference to the vector so in main program I can do something like this

```
int main(){

    test A;
    vector<string> c;
    c.push_back("test");
    ~A=c;
//i want to do it so the vector inside the class takes the value test,thats why i need reference

}
```

Update

The program works but it doesn't return reference to that class attribute, for example:

If i have something like this:

```
int main(){

       test A;
       A.v.push_back("bla");
       vector<string> c;
       c=~A;
      //This works, but if i want to change value of vector A to another vector declared in main
       vector<string> d;
       d.push_back("blabla");
       ~A=d;
       //the value of the A.v is not changed! Thats why i need a reference to A.v
  }
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this? It seems like an abuse of `operator~`.

Comment: ~A=c; <- How does that work?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/xMd0Ok), although overloading a negation operator to access a class member is completely insane. What problem are you having?

Comment: Please write a set method to set a member variable.

Comment: @KillAWatt1705: `~` is overloaded to return a reference to the vector contained in `A`; the expression assigns `c` to that vector.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Maybe it's implementing the new "custom destructor" idiom that's gaining popularity. :-)

Comment: @ArminVrević: (In response to a deleted comment) But you've got a reference to `A.v` since that's what the operator returns. Here's a [slightly better demonstration](http://ideone.com/JEMDjT) that prints the result of the assignment. Could you please post a complete demonstration of the code that fails to change `A.v`?

Comment: @ArminVrević: The new code *does* change `A.v`, as demonstrated [here](http://ideone.com/8PRsbU) (once I fix the compile error, since `A` has no `push_back` member). Could you please post a *complete compilable example* which *demonstrates* that it's not being changed when you think it should be.

Comment: @ArminVrević the *value* of `A.v` won't change but the content of the vector will. Yet another [working example](http://ideone.com/qYoLVT).

Comment: I see. Thank you, but what if I had example where interface was put in separate .h file, implementation in separate .cpp file and main in separate, I tried testing with that and it wouldnt work ( the old value would still be there ). What I mean is the first value would be assigned, and the new values wouldnt replace the old one, like it's a constant

Comment: @ArminVrević putting everything in three different files wouldn't change anything if it's done correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're doing `~A = d`, it's the same as `A.v = d` (if `v` were public).

It won't swap the old object `v` with the new object `d`, it will only replaces the contents of `A.v` with a copy of the contents of `d`, see [more information about `vector::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator=).

```
class test {
    vector<string> v;
  public:
    test() {
        v.push_back("Hello");
    }

    void print() {
        for(vector<string>::iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
            cout << *it;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    vector<string>& operator~() {
        return v;
    }      
};

int main(){
    test A;
    A.print();
    vector<string> c;
    c.push_back("world");
    ~A = c;
    A.print();
}
```

This outputs as expected (as you can see [here](http://ideone.com/ec78ta)) :

```
Hello
world
```